# What happens during fixation of Nucleic acids on nylon membrane

Tags: biochemistry, dna, lab-techniques

In Southern blotting technique, fixation of DNA to nylon membrane is a step prior to hybridisation with probe. It is done by baking at 80ºC and according to [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC306774/pdf/nar00005-0165.pdf) cross linking between DNA and nylon takes place.

What I am unable to understand is, if there is cross linking between DNA and nylon then, how does the probe bind complimentarily to the DNA? Isn't cross linking may mask the sites which may form hydrogen bonds?